# Python and Pylance, cannot access member

Tags: python, pylance, pyright

please, help me with python typing.
I use VSCode, so, by default it uses Pylance (based on Pyright).

In my services there are sometimes situations, where instantiation of a class depends on environment.

**Very simple example**

```
class SettingsA():
    ...


class SettingsB(SettingsA):
    param = 10


if os.getenv('env') == 'A':
    settings = SettingsA()
else:
    settings = SettingsB()


print(settings.param)
```

**But Pylance shows me an error**

```
Cannot access member "param" for type "SettingsA"
  Member "param" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
(variable) param: Unknown | int
```

While developing locally os.getenv('env') is always None or !='A'.

I know I can use # type: ignore. But it seems for me wrong in such situation.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because Pylance has to access environment variables and then analyze that condition. Apparently it doesn't do that. You may ask them on Github issues about the reason. (probably because it maybe hard to implement? hits the performance? can be error prone? idk)

All Pylance can say is that the type of `settings` is the Union of those two classes so it cannot have `param`, and it's saying the right thing.

One solution would be to define `param` on `SettingsA` and assign it to `None` (which means it doesn't have value). Basically `SettingsA` would have all the default values (which can be `None`) and  `SettingsB` overrides them.

Another option beside `# type: ignore` is `cast()`:

```py
from typing import cast

if os.getenv('env') == 'A':
    settings = SettingsA()
else:
    settings = SettingsB()

settings = cast(SettingsB, settings)
```

you do it once instead of ignoring the type every time you use `param` on `settings` object.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Also, maybe I could check if settings is instance of SettingsB in __init__.py or beginning of module file.

Comment: @Vadim Sure. That's another option. It's called "Type-Narrowing". Basically inside `isinstance(x, y)` block, the object `x` has the type of `y`.